# Can't get grunt.js task postcss with autoprefixer to work

Tags: javascript, css, json, gruntjs, autoprefixer

I am using [postcss](https://github.com/fabean/postcss-example/blob/master/gruntfile.js) with `autoprefixer-core` and cannot get it work.

The css is being output to the correct file, but autoprefixer is not having any effect. I have installed both postcss and autoprefixer with NPM. They are in my gruntfile.js file. Grunt is not outputting any errors so really hard to debug.

Here is my code:

```
module.exports = function( grunt ){
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-postcss');

        grunt.initConfig({
            //UGLIFY
            uglify:{
                my_target: {
                    files:{             
                        'js/main.min.js': ['js/main.js']
                    }//files
                }//my target
            },//uglify

            //COMPASS
            compass: {
                dev:{
                    options: {
                        config: 'config.rb'
                    }//options
                }//development mode
            },//compass

            //POST CSS
            postcss: {
                options: {
                    processors: [                       
                        require('autoprefixer-core')({browsers: 'last 2 version'}),
                    ]
                },
                dist: {
                    files: {
                        'css/prefixed/prefixed.css' : 'css/main.css' 
                    }
                }
            },

            //WATCH
            watch:{
                options: {livereload:true},
                scripts: {
                    files: ['js/main.js'],
                    tasks:['uglify']
                },//scripts
                sass: {
                    files: ['sass/**/*.scss'], 
                    tasks: ['compass:dev']
                },//sass
                html: {
                    files: ['*.html']   //watch all html files
                },//html
                postcss: {
                    files: 'css/main.css',
                    tasks: ['postcss']
                }
            }//watch
        }),//init config
        grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch', 'postcss'])
}//exports
```

The only difference in my code to the [demo on github](https://github.com/fabean/postcss-example/blob/master/gruntfile.js) is the line `require('autoprefixer-core')({browsers: 'last 2 version'})`. The demo includes `.postcss` on the end. If I do this I get an error: `Fatal error: undefined is not a function`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: where exactly are you getting that error? maybe `autoprefixer-core` is not available localy?

Answer (score 0):

The `browsers` value should be `last 2 versions` instead of `last 2 version`

```
processors: [                       
  require('autoprefixer-core')({browsers: 'last 2 versions'}),
]
```

See [browserslist#queries](https://github.com/ai/browserslist#queries) for other options

Answer (score 0):

You need to add autoprefixer-core to your local npm-packages.
In my case it was 'autoprefixer' and require:

```
require('autoprefixer')({
    browsers: ['last 2 versions']
})
```

This helps me.